# Iterate ArrayList and get match items Id

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains data like profId, firstname, lastname, age.

Now I have a lastname and firstname, which gets from user form side. Now I want to compare them with an ArrayList. If both match, I want to retrieve "respective profId".

e.g arraylist contains data like

> profId      lastname      fistname      age
>
> 1            roy            sam         25
>
> 2            ryob           arnav       30

Now user will type lastname and firstname as roy and sam respectively. I will get this data by their getter methods.

Now, how should I compare these 2 names with the ArrayList so that I will get the perfect profid of him as:

> '1'.

I am trying to compare by this way.

```
//  existPatList is arraylist patfamily is object of Family from where I will get users value

for(Family p : existPatList) {
    System.out.println("Last name" +p.getLastName());             
    System.out.println("First name"+p.getFirstName());
    if(p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(patFamily.getLastName())) {
        System.out.println("got it");       
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So what is the problem here? got any error/bug?

Comment: I am not able to get match and obviously its repective profId.

Comment: well thats _not a standard problem_..tell us what you are getting as output, until which line your code runs correctly as expected, where you get the error/bug, is your program control gets into `if` condition or not, what are the possible reasons that _why you are not able to get match_, it can be other reasons apart from your loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `&&` in your `if` condition with both `firstName` and `lastName`.

```
for(Family p : existPatList) {
   System.out.println("Last name" +p.getLastName());             
   System.out.println("First name"+p.getFirstName());
   if(p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(patFamily.getFirstName()) && p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(patFamily.getLastName())) {
       System.out.println("got it");       
   }
}
```

To get `profId` replace your line:

```
System.out.println("got it");
```

with

```
System.out.println(p.getProfId); //or do whatever you wanna do with profId
```

I consider here the you `getters` also has a get method for `profId`, that is `getProfId()`

Comment: I have tried this but its not working... and one thing after matching i want to get its respective profId , this is the main thing  for which i am doing this all things.

Comment: yes, i tried ur if condition, but control is not going inside if condition

Comment: yes whatever ur understood is perfect, i have profId field and has a getter & setter method inside Family. but still control is not going inside if condition

Comment: try getting `System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());` before `if` to know is your list _actually_ have those names which you are trying to match

Comment: yes , they are present inside arraylist , i have already checked it.

Comment: then there must be some other problem exist, because your loop and condition is correct to my knowledge..